# ASP.NET Core with windows auth always gives 403

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

Using Visual Studio 2019 I created a .NET Core API, and I told it to use windows authentication.  I then edited the WeatherForecastController.cs file and added a simple post route:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return NoContent();
}
```

If I then run the app locally, via VS, and try to POST to that, passing NTLM credentials, it still gives a forbidden (403) error.  I've seen multiple possible solutions to this from googling but nothing seems to work.

In my Startup.cs I have this

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

and in the ConfigureServices I added

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: Is your controller decorated with [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: @mac yes, the default template has that.

Comment: What does your startup.cs look like?

Comment: It's just the default that Visual studio creates.  I didn't edit anything except for adding the HttpPost.  It calls UseAuthorization in the Configure method, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Read up on .net core authentication schemes (this one specifically related to windows auth) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. Try adding services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);. Keep in mind the order in which you add the middleware in Configure is important: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order

Comment: @mac That was one of the thing I had tried earlier, unfortunately.  I updated the question to show my Configure.  I haven't done any IIS configuration because this is just running locally via the debugger, not deployed to an actual IIS site yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this had nothing to do with authentication.  Postman was returning a 403 no matter what.  I finally dropped down to doing it manually via curl and found the server was throwing an exception in a completely unrelated area.  Fixing that fixed the issue.

Comment: What was the issue? I am seeing the same thing

Comment: @Alex like I said it was unrelated. I don't even remember what.  Just try to use curl directly and you might see a better error. I frequently find Postman does silly things that hides the true issue.  I've all but stopped using it.